# No module named 'pynput.keyboard._darwin' for py2app macos app

Tags: python, py2app

When it comes to building a MacOS application from a Python project, "python3 setup.py py2app" is a popular command to use. However, as with any complex task, issues can arise that require troubleshooting.

In my case, I am running into an import problem while using this command. Specifically, certain modules or packages may not be properly imported, leading to errors or crashes within the application.

To address this issue, I am seeking the help of others who may have encountered similar problems or have expertise in this area. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice on how to fix this import issue.

In the meantime, I have included my setup.py file for reference. This file contains the necessary configuration settings for generating the MacOS application from my project. Perhaps someone with a keen eye for detail can spot the issue and suggest a solution.

As always, I am grateful for the support and collaboration of the coding community. Let's work together to create robust and reliable applications that make people's lives easier and more enjoyable.

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['start.py']
DATA_FILES = ['credentials.json', 'token.json']
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages': ['src'],
    'includes': ['pynput'], 
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'InstaMSG',
        'CFBundleDisplayName': 'InstaMSG',
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': 'InstaMSG',
        'CFBundleIdentifier': 'com.example.nathanvitivernovaes',
        'CFBundleVersion': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': '1.0.0',
        'LSUIElement': True,
    },
    'resources': ['credentials.json', 'token.json']
}

REQUIREMENTS = [
    "cachetools",
    "certifi",
    "charset-normalizer",
    "google-api-core",
    "google-api-python-client",
    "google-auth",
    "google-auth-httplib2",
    "google-auth-oauthlib",
    "googleapis-common-protos",
    "httplib2",
    "idna",
    "MouseInfo",
    "numpy",
    "oauthlib",
    "opencv-python",
    "Pillow",
    "protobuf",
    "pyasn1",
    "pyasn1-modules",
    "PyAutoGUI",
    "PyGetWindow",
    "PyMsgBox",
    "pynput",
]

setup(
    name='InstaMSG',
    version='1.0.0',
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=REQUIREMENTS,
)
```

```
  File "/Users/nathanvitiver/Documents/allbrave/insta-msg/dist/InstaMSG.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 522, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/nathanvitiver/Documents/allbrave/insta-msg/dist/InstaMSG.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 394, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/nathanvitiver/Documents/allbrave/insta-msg/dist/InstaMSG.app/Contents/Resources/start.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pynput.mouse import Button
  File "pynput/__init__.pyc", line 40, in <module>
  File "pynput/keyboard/__init__.pyc", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput/_util/__init__.pyc", line 76, in backend
ImportError: this platform is not supported: No module named 'pynput.keyboard._darwin'

Try one of the following resolutions:

 * Please make sure that you have Python bindings for the system frameworks installed
2023-03-04 12:11:11.423 InstaMSG[30040:228480] Launch error
2023-03-04 12:11:11.423 InstaMSG[30040:228480] Launch error
See the py2app website for debugging launch issues
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `pynput` to the packages list in `OPTIONS`. It works for me.

Updated version:

```
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'packages': ['src', 'pynput'],
    'includes': ['pynput'], 
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'InstaMSG',
        'CFBundleDisplayName': 'InstaMSG',
        'CFBundleGetInfoString': 'InstaMSG',
        'CFBundleIdentifier': 'com.example.nathanvitivernovaes',
        'CFBundleVersion': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': '1.0.0',
        'LSUIElement': True,
    },
    'resources': ['credentials.json', 'token.json']
}
```